# summary function from torchsummary printing its output twice

Tags: python, pytorch, data-science

So I have been trying to implement a CNN-based solution for classification as proposed in this paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.08923.pdf). Here is my code for reproduction. It's a fairly simple implementation but I don't understand why would the torchsummary would yield such a result. I have gone through their GitHub Q&A as well but there is no such issue raised so far as well.

```py
class CNN_Pred2D(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_filters=[8,8,8], debug=True):
        super().__init__()
        self.debug = debug
        
        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(1, n_filters[0], kernel_size=(1,82)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(n_filters[0], n_filters[0], kernel_size=(3,1)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2,1)),
            
            nn.Conv2d(n_filters[0], n_filters[1], kernel_size=(3,1)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2,1)),
            
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear(104,1),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

        
    def forward(self, X):
        out = self.model(X)
#         print(out.shape)
        return out

model = CNN_Pred2D().to(device)

summary(model, [(1, 60,82)])
```

Here is its output:

[image]

Comment: Did you try resetting/restarting the **ipython** kernel? Looking at the snippet you posted it would seem that it is a glitch. As such this won't hamper the functioning of the NN.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same problem, but realized that this is due to jupyter notebooks printing the last returned object in a cell. Turns out `summary(model, [(1, 60,82)])` both **prints** AND **returns** the model summary. Thus the print and the returned value are shown.

Use `_ = summary(model, [(1, 60,82)])` at the end of the cell to catch the returned value and only show the print,
or `summary(model, [(1, 60,82)], verbose = 0)` to only show the returned value (if executed AT THE END of a cell).

Also see the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/torch-summary/) for reference.

Comment: You may also be able to simply add a semi-colon after `summary(model, [(1, 60,82)])` **to get only one view of the summary after running that cell**. Keep in mind **the very last expression** in a typical Jupyter cell is special. What the last expression of each cell returns gets displayed by default. So by putting a semi-colon after that text **on the last line** like `summary(model, [(1, 60,82)]);` it means that the `;` colon is the last expression the Python kernel sees in that cell and that evaluates to nothing, and so nothing is displayed from what is returned. While your advice is ...

Comment: <continued> best for pure Python use in this case, how that is working won't be very obvious to Python/Jupyter novices. Whereas the use of the semi-colon as the last item on the last line of a Jupyter cell can be convenient in a broad manner for related situations such as this that will be encountered while working in Jupyter's Python kernel & may be picked up more readily by novices. I base on that assumption that it may look like a Jupyter style/syntax approach they'd have seen elsewhere perhaps, and that it relies less on understanding the Python idiom of unpacking to dummy variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can try  [**torchinfo**](https://github.com/tyleryep/torchinfo) instead of **torchsummary**.

```
from torchinfo import summary

summary(model, (1, 60,82))
```